# Chrome ignores my if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a [page](http://koninghealth.com/providers/) I'm working on. When a user scrolls down to the tabs ("Existing workflow" and "KBCT workflow"), I'd like to change an "Existing workflow" tab to a "KBCT workflow" one with a 5-second delay only. This need to be executed only when the tabs are visible (user scrolled to that position).

Here is the code

```
tabs = jQuery('#kbct-tabs');
kbctTab = tabs.find('.tab:last-child');

if (tabs.css('visibility') === 'visible') {
  setTimeout(function() {
    kbctTab.click();
    console.log('executed');
  }, 5000);
}
```

And I don't know what's wrong with it, particulary the if statement. It works, but not how it's supposed to. It seems like the browser ignores the if statement and starts to count 5 seconds after the page has loaded, not when a user has scrolled to the tabs. BUT when I write that if statement in the Chrome Console, it works like it's supposed to.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFMDX.png).

Can you please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: visibility property does not depend on user scroll

Comment: provide a [mcve]. A link to a live page will rot making this question useless in the future

Comment: @avramch: you're probably looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/2770274

Comment: @Adassko thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working 100%.

You just need to change 2 things:

1 - Add an [scroll](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event listener (`element.scroll(callback)`)

2 - Use the [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) property to check visibily. (`element.scrollTop()`)

```
 var kbctworkflow = function () {
    var tabs = jQuery('#kbct-tabs');
    var kbctTab = tabs.find('.tab:last-child');
    if ($(document.body).scrollTop() > tabs.offset().top - 300) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        kbctTab.click();
        console.log('executed');
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
  $(window).scroll(kbctworkflow);
```

DEMO http://jsbin.com/qatice/2/edit?js,output

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that a bit more?

Comment: Sure ... updated the answer with a DEMO and the working code.

Comment: But how to execute it only once? Right now, it's executed 200+ times.

Comment: It will execute every time the user scrolls and the element is below the scrollTop, you can use a boolean and an if statement to make it happen only once.

Answer (score -1):

try using jquery's `is` selector.

```
tabs = jQuery('#kbct-tabs');
kbctTab = tabs.find('.tab:last-child');

if (tabs.is(':visibile')) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    kbctTab.click();
    console.log('executed');
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Didn't help :( It starts to count 5 seconds when the page has loaded, not when tabs become visible

Comment: Why the down vote? You could have just emphasized that I missed the "This need to be executed only when the tabs are visible (user scrolled to that position)" part.